# Selecting a listbox dropdown item in GWT

Tags: gwt, listbox

I have a GWT view from which I grab the value of a dropdown and store it in a DB. The dropdown has the values "one" "two" "three". When I go back to the same view and I have "Two" stored in the DB then I want "Two" to be the selected item.  However the only way I can get this to work at the moment is by iterating through each item in the listbox to find the one which matches and then set this as the selected one.  Is there a better way to achieve this? I don't want to have to save the selected index.

Comment: Which 'dropdown' are you using? GWT's `ListBox` or `ValueListBox`? GXT's `ComboBox`? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to extend ListBox and implement TakesValue interface. And in this class maintain a list variable which holds all the items in the ListBox. setValue and getValue should looks like the following code snippet -

```
private List<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

public class MyListBox extends ListBox implements TakesValue<String>
{
         public void setValue( String value )
         {
        if ( listItems.size() > 0 )
        {
            int valueIndex = 0;
            if ( listItems.contains( value ) )
            {
                valueIndex = listItems.indexOf( value );
                this.value = value;
            }
            setItemSelected( valueIndex, true );
        }
        }

        public String getValue()
        {
        int selectedIndex = super.getSelectedIndex();
        String value = null;
        if ( selectedIndex >= 0 )
        {
            value = super.getValue( selectedIndex );
            if ( "null".equals( value ) )
            {
                value = null;
            }
        }

        return value;
        }

        public void setOptions(List<String> options)
        {
              listItems.clear();
              listItems.addAll( items );
              for ( String item : listItems )
              {
                    addItem( item, item );
              }
        }
}
```

Now its just a matter of doing listBox.setValue( value ) method call from the view java file. Prior to this options must be set.

Comment: It does not even compile:
1. `this.value = value;`  value is not declared in the class as instance variable;
2. `listItems.addAll(items);`  `items` is never declared.
3. Method `setOptions` is not used and it's not clear where and how to use it.

Comment: @belgoros, thanks for pointing at errors. You are the first person to expect compilable code snippet in stack overflow. Keep it up